# Is there a way to change treeview table's column numbers in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I need to change a Treeview table's column number and the table's content in python tkinter but seems very difficult, below is the code and the result view, please take a look of it and give me some idea if there's any solution for it, thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
window = tk.Tk()

colName = ['B','C']

def change_table():
global table       
new_colName = ['A'] + colName
table = ttk.Treeview(window, columns = ('0','1','2'), show = 'headings')
for i in range(len(new_colName)):
    table.heading(i, text = new_colName[i])

button = ttk.Button(window, text="Three Columns", command=change_table)
button.pack()

table = ttk.Treeview(window, columns = ('0','1'), show = 'headings')
for i in range(len(colName)):
table.heading(i, text = colName[i])
data = [20,30]
table.insert(parent='', index=0, iid=0,value=data) 
table.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[This is the running result,the button doesn't work as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8et2j.png)

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working? What are you expecting that is different from what it does? Also, the code yo posted seems to have some broken indentation.

Comment: My intention is to change the number of columns from 2 to 3 once the button was pressed but the number remains 2 using my code, so my code doesn't work. For the indentation I don't know why the broken happens, I'm using a Mac book and the code tool to make the indentations seems not working, so I have to manually add spaces to create the indentions... this isn't efficient but my code is not so long, so it's just fine. Sorry for the broken indentation happening anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recomend using a OOP approach for Tkinter scripts since it makes things much more structured. Also in your case this way you can waive the use of `global` to reference your table.

I refactored your code to an classbased approach and fixed your problem:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Treeview


class Window(Tk):
    headers = ['B', 'C']
    data = [20, 30]

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Table_expander')
        self.expand_btn = Button(self, text="Three Columns")
        self.expand_btn.pack()
        self.table = Treeview(self, columns=('0', '1'), show='headings')
        for pos, heading in enumerate(Window.headers):
            self.table.heading(pos, text=heading)
        # inserting returns the id --> catch to edit later
        self.inserted_data = self.table.insert(parent='', index=0, values=Window.data)
        self.table.pack()
        self.expand_btn.config(command=self.change_table)

    def change_table(self):
        new_headers = ['A'] + Window.headers
        # config table to show three columns
        self.table.config(columns=('0', '1', '2'), show='headings')
        for pos, header in enumerate(new_headers):
            self.table.heading(pos, text=header)
        # change values in columns with the caught ID
        self.table.item(self.inserted_data, values=[0]+Window.data)


# Start skript (instanciate Tk window and mainloop) if file is executed
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window()
    app.mainloop()
```

- when adding a column use the table you created instead of instanciating a new one (do this with config)
- you defined the position of the values when inserting them, so they dont change places if you simply add and rearange the headers, therefore edit the table item

Comment: Thank you very much for the modified code and the detailed explanation, I agree the structure looks much better!